# How to call powershell script located on network from Java program?

Tags: java, powershell, networking

I am trying to use the following program using `ProcessBuilder`. This program contains local path but **I want to call the same script located on network**.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TestPowershell {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        //Process proc = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c powershell.exe  C:\\get-sevice-gsvc.ps1"); // old code

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("powershell", "-file", "C:\\get-sevice-gsvc.ps1", "127.0.0.1");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process proc = pb.start();

        InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
         try{


       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
       {
            System.out.println(line);

       }
        reader.close();
        proc.getOutputStream().close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: u wish to download the script from net and then run it? Or send a request to server so that server can run it

Comment: this script is located on the remote box which needs to be run and then I will process the output in the while loop. I don't need to download. There is no application or server running on the remote box. I mean there is no receiver on the remote machine. It's a plain java call to a remote powershell script.

Comment: u have a connection with shell on remote machine? I mean some kind of ssh connections setup?

Comment: It's a windows box. I don't know about connection. All I am trying to call from Java is that there is a shared network folder like \\pcname\\Sharedfoldername\\powershellscript.ps1

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you want the script to actually execute (local or remote)?

Comment: I want to execute powershell script remotely and process result in my program. I have tried using Processbuilder like ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "powershell", "-file", "C:\\get-sevice-gsvc.ps1", "x.x.x.x");

Comment: Huh? Do you want your java app to tell ANOTHER computer to run the script and return the results to you, or is powershell installed on the machine running java? If you want another computer to run the code, you should create a server for you that you can call through an API or something. It's much easier to just install powershell on your computer, then run `powershell -file \\myserver\myscript.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need the script to run on the box it is residing on. In this case it is not that simple (otherwise, you would simply use a network path as you indicated already). If you use *ProcessBuilder* then the script will be run on the machine where your Java code is executing regardless where the script is residing on. In order to run the script remotely you can use *PowerShell* since it is able to connect to another machine and run commands there. In this case you would write a simple *PowerShell* script that calls the original one remotely, and start this new script on your machine using *ProcessBuilder* instead of the original one. However, there are some hurdles to be taken. Most of them deal with user rights. Take the time to study *PowerShell* documentation for *Remote Command Execution*, or search StackOverflow or other places for this topic.